# How to do the following problem via argument theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Suppose that $$f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{17}(z-\frac{\pi}{n}), \ z\in \mathbb{C}$$ and $\gamma(t)=e^{2it}, t\in [0, 2\pi]$. If $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\, dz=\alpha\pi i,$$ then the value of $\alpha$ is

As- By argument principle, we know that $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\, dz=2\pi i(Z-P).$$
Here $P$ denotes the number of poles and $Z$ denotes the number of zeros. In this case, we have $Z=17$. But the answer is $56$. Please tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

- $\gamma$ surrounds the origin *twice,* not once.
- Only the zeros of $f$ in the interior of the unit disk must be taken into account, that makes 14 zeros, not 17.

Therefore
$$
\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\, dz = 2 \cdot 2 \pi i \cdot 14 \, .
$$

Comment: Can you please tell which zeros are not on the unit circle? The zeros are $\frac{\pi}{n}$ for $n=1, \cdots, 17$.

Comment: $|\pi/n| < 1$ only if $n \ge 4$.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you.